# setting up tinymce with cloudinary in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I've read the readme file at https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_tinymce but still can't understand how to do it. Plus they do it on Ruby on Rails, which doesn't really help.

Do I really need to do server-side endpoint? It only asks for a signed URL. But I don't need it to be signed. How do I do it within JavaScript and HTML alone? I don't want to do anything inside my server except to render templates.

edit: I tried it with `image_upload handler` and it uploads to my Cloudinary account. But it won't give me the url for the image on successful upload (I expect to get something like `https://res.cloudinary.com/strova/image/upload/v1527068409/asl_gjpmhn.jpg`). Here's my code:

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/strova/upload');

            xhr.onload = function () {
                var json;

                if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }

                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);



                success(json.location);
            };

            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            formData.append('upload_preset', cloudinary_upload_preset);

            xhr.send(formData);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "faking" a POST request for one. I am still trying. To figure out why the documentation "requires" a POST request. The PHP example: https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x//TinyMCE3x@Installation/ just echos back what gets POSTED to server. The plugin must be interpolated the **posted** content.

Comment: I tried doing it with images_upload_handler method stated in the docs. Configured the settings a little bit and it uploads to my cloudinary url, but it won't give me the url for the image on successful upload. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your code, I was able to resolve this pain point for myself. The missing part was that after parsing the response, the secure_url from the response needed to be called and assigned to json in the format required by TinyMCE. Following is the code:

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;

//restricted it to image only using resource_type = image in url, you can set it to auto for all types 

            xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<yourcloudname>/image/upload');

            xhr.onload = function () {

                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    var url = response.secure_url; //get the url 
                    var json = {location: url}; //set it in the format tinyMCE wants it
                    success(json.location);
                }
            };

            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            formData.append('upload_preset', '<YourUnsignedUploadPreset>');

            xhr.send(formData);
        }
```